# In Eclipse, how do I define standard paths for C++ include headers?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I write my C++ projects using the Eclipse IDE. Anytime I start a new project, I have to define all the include paths. Is there a way for me to define a set of standard header paths that have to be included in all projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to get settings between workspaces
In your old (working) project Do File/Export... C/C++ Project Settings and give it a file to write to

In your new workspace do File/Import... C/C++ Project Settings and select your file

This also works nicely for all the other customizations you might have such as key bindings.

Comment: I don't like this approach, I think that something more simple should exist. It's obvious that I want to use the header of std for example in all my project. Why I have to import it every time, or "paste and copy" some settings?